# Duda con map y split de string

Tags: javascript

```js
var MORSE_CODE = {"a": ".-", "b": "-...", "c": "-.-.", "d": "-..", "e": ".", "f": "..-.", "g": "--.", "h": "....", "i": "..", "j": ".---", "k": "-.-", "l": ".-..", "m": "--", "n": "-.", "o": "---", "p": ".--.", "q": "--.-", "r": ".-.", "s": "...", "t": "-", "u": "..-", "v": "...-", "w": ".--", "x": "-..-", "y": "-.--", "z": "--..", "1": ".----", "2": "..---", "3": "...--", "4": "....-", "5": ".....", "6": "-....", "7": "--...", "8": "---..", "9": "----.", "0": "-----", " ": "|"};
    
function encodeMorse(string){
      var words = (string).split(' ');
      var letters = words.map((w) => w.split(' '));
      var encoded = [];
    
      for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
        encoded[i] = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < letters[i].length; x++){
            if(MORSE_CODE[letters[i][x]]){
                encoded[i].push( MORSE_CODE[letters[i][x]]);
            }
        }
      }
      return encoded.map(arr => arr.join('')).join(' ');
}

function do_code(str){
     document.getElementById('morse_res').value = encodeMorse(str);
}
```

Estoy transformando el código de https://steelx.gitbooks.io/javascript-algorithms/decode-the-morse-code.html

No logro hacer que devuelva nada, la separación por letras parece no estar correcta. morse res es un input de resultado y str es la palabra o palabras a decodificar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentario particular, cuando transmites un mensaje en clave morse hay una pausa entre letras. Por ejemplo cuando transmites "et" el mensaje es `.<pausa>-` y no `.-` que se leería igual que la letra "a". Por lo mismo, me parece que en tu ejercicio cada letra en morse debes separarla por ejemplo con un espacio. De la misma manera, para diferenciar un espacio explícito (entre palabras) de esta pausa implícita, tu diccionario ASCII - Morse tiene un `|` para los espacios. Entre radioaficionados usualmente un punto dura un `tick`, una raya dura tres `ticks` y un silencio de tres `ticks` indica que terminó la letra y va a comenzar otra. Una pausa de siete `ticks` indica que se acabó una palabra y viene otra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dicho esto, en javascript (y otros lenguajes) un `string` tiene comportamientos similares a un array. Tiene un atributo `length` como largo total del texto, y puede accederse a sus caracteres usando `.charAt(posicion)`, de manera que no necesitas explotar el texto de entrada para recorrerlo.

Incluso si explotas el texto separándolo en un array de palabras, no necesitas explotar a su vez cada palabra en letras. En tu código, por otro lado, tampoco lograrías eso explotando una palabra usando `.split(' ')` dado que la palabra no contiene espacios dentro de sí misma. Lo que tú querías hacer se lograría explotando con `.split('')` que es, literalmente, convertir un string en un array de caracteres. Eso, como te dije, no es necesario dado que el string mismo puedes tratarlo como array.

Te dejo un snippet que toma todo lo que escribes en un input y lo transforma en morse con dos reglas:

- Cada letra es un código morse seguido de un espacio (para distinguirlo del código que sigue)
- Cada espacio es explícitamente un separador `|` acorde a tu diccionario. Esto es una convención arbitraria basada en tu diccionario y no en la convención entre radioaficionados.

```js
var MORSE_CODE = {"a": ".-", "b": "-...", "c": "-.-.", "d": "-..", "e": ".", "f": "..-.", "g": "--.", "h": "....", "i": "..", "j": ".---", "k": "-.-", "l": ".-..", "m": "--", "n": "-.", "o": "---", "p": ".--.", "q": "--.-", "r": ".-.", "s": "...", "t": "-", "u": "..-", "v": "...-", "w": ".--", "x": "-..-", "y": "-.--", "z": "--..", "1": ".----", "2": "..---", "3": "...--", "4": "....-", "5": ".....", "6": "-....", "7": "--...", "8": "---..", "9": "----.", "0": "-----", " ": "|"};

function charToMorse(char) {
   return (MORSE_CODE[char]||'') +' ';
}

function encodeMorse(value){
      var salida='',
          largo = value.length;
      for(var i=0; i<largo; i++) {
         salida+=charToMorse(value.charAt(i));
      }
      document.querySelector('#resultado').innerText=salida.trim();
}


document.querySelector('#entrada').addEventListener('keyup',function(e) {
  encodeMorse(this.value.toLowerCase().trim());
});
```

```css
.contenedor {
float:left;margin-right:3px;width:40%;
}
#entrada {
width:90%;
}
#resultado {
width:90%;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor" >
<p>El texto</p>
<input type="text" id="entrada">
</div>
<div class="contenedor">
<p>Se convierte a</p>
<textarea id="resultado"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Edit**: por sugerencia del OP [Pablo Rodríguez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/105766/pablo-rodriguez), acabo de incluir la lógica para transformar a minúsculas antes de la transformación. Otro acercamiento implicaría repetir código o encontrarse con caracteres sin traducción.

Comment: Gracias amenadiel. Tengo que revisar lo de los espacios. Bdom es textual a mi codigo y no me funciona. Entendí lo de Amena voy a modificarlo

Comment: Funciona, le cambie el | por los siete espacios. también le quite el ultimo al resultado.

Comment: oh! claro, el resultado tiene que devolverse con un `.trim()` porque la última letra tendrá un espacio de más

Comment: `value = value.toLowerCase();` ayuda para resolver problemas con las mayusculas

Comment: Buen detalle, voy a editar

Answer (score 1):

Coloqué un input, donde tecleas una palabra y te imprime de vuelta lo que escribiste y la cadena en clave morse:

```js
var MORSE_CODE = {"a": ".-", "b": "-...", "c": "-.-.", "d": "-..", "e": ".", "f": "..-.", "g": "--.", "h": "....", "i": "..", "j": ".---", "k": "-.-", "l": ".-..", "m": "--", "n": "-.", "o": "---", "p": ".--.", "q": "--.-", "r": ".-.", "s": "...", "t": "-", "u": "..-", "v": "...-", "w": ".--", "x": "-..-", "y": "-.--", "z": "--..", "1": ".----", "2": "..---", "3": "...--", "4": "....-", "5": ".....", "6": "-....", "7": "--...", "8": "---..", "9": "----.", "0": "-----", " ": "|"};
    
function encodeMorse(cadena){
     //Removemos los espacios del split en words y letters
      var words = cadena.split('');
      var letters = words.map((w) => w.split(''));
      var encoded = [];
    
      for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
        encoded[i] = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < letters[i].length; x++){
            if(MORSE_CODE[letters[i][x]]){
                encoded[i].push( MORSE_CODE[letters[i][x]]);
            }
        }
      }
      return encoded.map(arr => arr.join('')).join(' ');
}

function do_code(){
    var x = document.getElementById('morse_res').value;
    console.log(x);
    var y = encodeMorse(x);
    console.log(y);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="morse_res"/>


<button onclick="do_code()">Click me</button>
```

Según el código debes escribir las palabras con espacios ya que en base a eso utiliza el `split`, puedes hacer que el `split` funcione por cada letra removiendo los espacios de en medio.

Espero sea de tu ayuda.